# What is wrong with this question? (Failed audit)

Tags: discussion, review-audits, needs-more-focus

I was performing some review on the site and came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15573084) on the open review votes.

The question looked good to me, so I voted for it to be reopened, but the system told me it was an audit and I failed it.

Now, the question was initially closed because it was "unclear what you're asking". But to me, it seems pretty clear what the question is: how is the code able to instantiate a new object from a variable (class).

Now, this may be considered beginner-level of JavaScript usage, but regardless, the question seems very precise. And if it was indeed considered a very low quality level for the knowledge of the language required, then we do have very popular questions of this matter and a wrong usage of the flags.

So, I'm not really sure: did I choose wrong in this case? This was an example of several questions I've seen in a similar state. Is there a way to determine when questions are "good enough" to be considered SO specific questions and not too broad?

**Update:** Here's the question for those claiming that they can't see it:

> I understand that T is an object of Twit and that objects can be made from classes. But from this declaration it looks like T is being made from a variable and not a class. Can someone clarify please?
>
> ```
> var Twit = require('twit')
>
> var T = new Twit({
>     consumer_key:         '...',
>     consumer_secret:      '...',
>     access_token:         '...',
>     access_token_secret:  '...'
> })
> ```

Comment: Odd - are you seeing the notice that states "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully"? I'm confused why that's there as there are no flags (let alone spam flags) on the question at all.

Comment: @ChrisF: That's not unheard of, at least in my experience, especially on audits; I suspect there's actually a ~10% chance of showing that on audits for no other reason than verisimilitude.

Comment: @ChrisF I'm guessing that something in the system automatically identified it as possibly abusive based on the use of the word "twit." That's not horribly offensive in American English, but my understanding is that some cultures consider it significantly more offensive.

Comment: @EdCottrell This makes my uncle's distaste for Twitter much more understandable...

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Lol. I think there are lots of other possible reasons for that. :)

Comment: @EdCottrell. Which cultures find it "significantly" more offensive? Surely not any english-speaking cultures, given the word's accepted meanings. Are you sure you're not confusing it with the superficially similar word spelled with an "a"?

Comment: @ekhumoro No, I'm aware of that other word, and that's not what I'm thinking of. I don't know if my impression is correct, but I'm basing that impression on interactions with a few folks who considered "twit" far more offensive than I do. The conversations that come immediately to mind were, I think, all with South Africans. I don't know how representative those individuals were of their countrymen. In any case, it's not a particularly *nice* word in any variant of English, so I'm just speculating that some automatic filter may have tripped on it.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question that should be reopened. That being said, not a perfect audit either.

Comment: Closed as unclear what you're AUDITING by Pointy, ZdaR, acontell, Abdulla Nilam, Flown.

Comment: I got a "question not found" ?

Comment: @Julian The question has been deleted so you need 10K+ rep to see it.

Comment: @EdCottrell - might that be cause the SA accent makes A sound more like I, so upon hearing twit, they assume the speaker said twat? :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Actually, I remember asking about that and ruling it out.

Comment: You should quote the question here. It is "unclear what you are asking" because without 10k rep I can't see what the problem question is.

Comment: @NickGammon Done! Very weird that I can still see it, I have only 3K.

Comment: You can see it, because you handled that review task. You should be able to have the same amount of information as when you reviewed the post.

Comment: @Braiam That explains it -- thanks!

Comment: @EdCottrell I'm a Saffer and "twit" is no more or less offensive to me than any other epithet.

Comment: @IanKemp Well, then I have no idea. But I'll keep that in mind should I need an epithet to hurl at you. :)